# Replacing a substring in a string that is in between (') in Python 3.6

Tags: string, python-3.x, pandas, replace

Have a column in a dataframe that is a series of messages.  Each string has block of 'characters' of different length that needs to be replaced.  It looks similar to this:

```
Index  Message    
0      The value '0000' is not valid.
1      The value 'GA1234' for <category> must be changed.
2      The value '.30' is not a valid entry.
3      The value 'Invitation for Party' is not valid.
4      On line '0010', the value 'CARD' is invalid.
```

Not sure how to replace all of the strings in the series in between the (').

Tried: df.Message.str.replace("The value '%'", 'The value XXXXX') but no luck.

Tried: df.Message.str.find(" ' ") which gives me the position of the first apostrophe but not sure about how to find the second apostrophe.

Is there a way I can take the substring between the two (') and replace them with 'XXXXX'?

Comment: This is what [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) are for.

Comment: Especially if there is a possibility of escape characters, then yes, RegEx. For example, how to handle a value such as `'That\'s a test'`

Comment: Never used a regular expression before.  Saw a few examples that started with "import re" but haven't got it figured out yet.

Answer (score 3):

[Series.str.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) accepts RegEx'es:

```
In [184]: df
Out[184]:
   Index                                            Message
0      0                     The value '0000' is not valid.
1      1  The value 'GA1234' for <category> must be chan...
2      2              The value '.30' is not a valid entry.
3      3     The value 'Invitation for Party' is not valid.
4      4       On line '0010', the value 'CARD' is invalid.

In [185]: df['Message'] = df['Message'].str.replace(r"'.*?'", 'XXXXX')

In [186]: df
Out[186]:
   Index                                          Message
0      0                    The value XXXXX is not valid.
1      1  The value XXXXX for <category> must be changed.
2      2            The value XXXXX is not a valid entry.
3      3                    The value XXXXX is not valid.
4      4       On line XXXXX, the value XXXXX is invalid.
```

Comment: This is the appropriate `pandas` response (-:  Though I do like Martijn's regex.

Comment: The pandas version works!  I have to learn .str.replace(r"'.*?'", 'XXXXX') I'll look for where I can find those wildcards but that helps a lot.  Also looking for the regex method so I can learn that.

Comment: @ArthurD.Howland, glad we could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"'[^']+'")  # 1 or more characters between single quotes
result = pattern.sub('XXXXX', inputtext)
```

The above will only accept two single quotes with one or more characters in between (which are themselves anything but single quotes).

See the [*Regular Expression HOWTO*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) included in Python's documentation for a good introduction on how to use patterns like these.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"'[^']+'")
>>> pattern.sub('XXXXX', "The value '0000' is not valid.")
'The value XXXXX is not valid.'
>>> pattern.sub('XXXXX', "The value 'GA1234' for <category> must be changed.")
'The value XXXXX for <category> must be changed.'
>>> pattern.sub('XXXXX', "The value '.30' is not a valid entry.")
'The value XXXXX is not a valid entry.'
>>> pattern.sub('XXXXX', "The value 'Invitation for Party' is not valid.")
'The value XXXXX is not valid.'
>>> pattern.sub('XXXXX', "On line '0010', the value 'CARD' is invalid.")
'On line XXXXX, the value XXXXX is invalid.'
```

If you have a Pandas Series, use [`Series.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html); it takes regular expressions too if you set `regex=True`, essentially acting as `re.sub()` calls for all values in the series:

```
df.Message.replace(r"'[^']+'", 'XXXXX', regex=True)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import pandas as df
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'Message': pd.Series([
...         "The value '0000' is not valid.",
...         "The value 'GA1234' for <category> must be changed.",
...         "The value '.30' is not a valid entry.",
...         "The value 'Invitation for Party' is not valid.",
...         "On line '0010', the value 'CARD' is invalid.",
...     ])
... })
>>> df.Message.replace(r"'[^']+'", 'XXXXX', regex=True)
0                      The value XXXXX is not valid.
1    The value XXXXX for <category> must be changed.
2              The value XXXXX is not a valid entry.
3                      The value XXXXX is not valid.
4         On line XXXXX, the value XXXXX is invalid.
Name: Message, dtype: object
```

Comment: also you can use `pattern.search("The value '0000' is not valid").group()` to find only the matched text.

Comment: pattern = re.compile(r"' [^']+ '")
df['Revised'] = pattern.sub('XXXXXX', df.Message)
Gets a Type Error: expected string or bytes-like object.

Comment: @ArthurD.Howland: use `Series.apply()`, don't pass the whole `Series` to `pattern.sub(..)`.

Comment: @ArthurD.Howland: in other words, you can't just vectorise pattern substitution. `df['Revised'] = df.Message.apply(lambda v: pattern.sub('XXXXX', v))`.

Comment: @ArthurD.Howland: however, `Series.replace(..., regex=True)` lets you do the substitution on a series directly.